# Разработка приложений для Android

Tags: java, android, c++

Я учусь java и разработке на Android и тут я задумался над одним вопросом. Как понять, что технические характеристики смартфона будут поддерживать мою программу? Как понять, какие технические характеристики нужны смартфону, чтобы она работала? Где про это можно прочитать углубленно или сами расскажите эксперты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для андроид разработчика такие вещи не очень важны. Вы должны ориентироваться только на версию андроида. Ну если вы делаете что-то с использованием NDK, то тогда стоит еще посмотреть в сторону процессоров. А остальное все не так важно.

Comment: просто у меня у самого смартфон android 4.1.2, Оперативки 1 гб и мне самому хочется, чтобы мой смартфон тоже работал с моими программами)

Comment: Да все будет работать. У меня есть для тестов смартфон на 2.3. И на нем все что поддерживается, все работает. Главное пишите так, чтобы утечек памяти не было.

Comment: и ты сказал, что если с NDK, то посмотреть в сторону процессора. А что смотреть?

Comment: NDK это c++. У разных процессоров есть свои особенности работы. И для них по разному пишется код. Например есть библиотека Realm. Она написана на плюсах. И когда ты ее подключаешь, то приложение начинает на 10 мегабайт весить больше. Это все из-за того, что она тянет код под разные архитектуры процессора

Comment: @pavel163, ну зачем вы про особенности работы сразу. При разработке нативных приложений это не так важно. Тем более что речь идёт о четырёх типовых архитектурах для телефонов. Важно просто осознание того факта, что есть разные `ABI` и для каждого должна быть своя нативная библиотека скомпилирована.

Comment: @user1056837 вы правы. Не надо было так сразу в особенности)))

Answer (score 5):

Лучше не думать, "потянет" или нет тот или иной смартфон ваше приложение, а писать приложения таким образом, чтобы не было явных просадок по производительности.

Т.е. использовать стандартные подходы для поиска, сортировки, хранения данных. Не стараться самому писать велосипеды; следить, чтобы ресурсы использовались оптимально и т.д.

По сути нужно просто включать здравый смысл и не костылить.

PS
Ещё неплохо бы почитать про `ABI` - это и есть различные архитектуры. Но это важно при включении (разработке) нативных библиотек.